# "Есовский" или "еэсовский" — относящийся к ЕС?

Tags: грамотная-речь, прилагательные, аббревиатуры

МИД РФ настаивает на написании ***ЕСовский***, а не ***ЕЭСовский***, в значении *имеющий отношение к ЕС* (Европейский Союз). Потому что есть еще ЕЭС (Европейское экономическое сообщество), и может возникнуть путаница.

Допустимо ли написание ***есовский***?

Многие считают, что нет: [**грамота.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B5%D1%8D%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Comment: Можно посмотреть, где это МИД на таком настаивает? Если это правда, то они явно не в свою епархию залезли. Но ведь не поспоришь же с такой структурой.

Answer (score 1):

Тут проблема не в правописании, про которое Грамота.ру ответила чётко, а в терминологии и возникшей омонимии. Грамотным выходом из этой ситуации было бы  прилагательное **евросоюзный**, но далеко не факт, что его всё-таки  будут использовать вместо неправильного "есовый".